# Using a date value in where clause on a datetime data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there anything I should be cautious of when using a date in the where statement if the field I am filtering on is a datetime? Does WHERE Date = '20190604' actually get interpreted as '2019-06-04 00:00:00'

Ran a few queries to see if any values drop based on the different ways the date can be formatted.  Did not notice any difference.

```
SELECT DateField
FROM CalendarTbl
WHERE DateField = '20190604'
```

Comment: There are [only a few formats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe) where this conversion is predictable. The one you're using happens to be one of them, fortunately.

Comment: Yes it will be implicitly cast to a datetime with a time of 00 as you asked. That means that only those rows with that exact time would be returned. You would need to use convert(date, DateField) = '20190604' to get all rows from that specific day.

Comment: Always use properly formatted dates. To make code clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: Your Format is the ISO format, it is reputed to always work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a string like `'20190604'` to a `datetime` then yes, it'll be interpreted as the date and time `2019-06-04T00:00:00.000`. This means that if you have any values that aren't on the stroke of midnight then the row won't be returned (even if that value is `2019-06-04T00:00:00.003`).

If you do have values other than at midnight and you want to return all rows for a specific date you can use `CONVERT`/`CAST` to change the data type of the column to `date`; which is still SARGable:

```
SELECT DateField
FROM CalendarTbl
WHERE CONVERT(date,DateField) = '20190604';
```

Comment: Conversion from datetime to date is SARGable? Interesting. Is this documented?

Comment: I'm not sure it actually appears in any documentation, @GeorgeMenoutis , however, there are plenty of articles that discuss it, such as [here](https://datatellblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/24/sql-server-query-optimization-sargable-functions/).

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis: SARGability as a concept isn't even documented, so that's too much to hope for. It is [known](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/97345), though. (But note the caveats discussed in the answer.)

Comment: You should read Martin Smith's answer to [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) on dba.StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's fine. Your string gets implicitly cast to the needed datetime.  I'd wager it's the fastest way for human-inputting dates.

Check the colored table in the [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for a list of implicit and explicit casts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the string literal '20190604' will always be interpreted by SQL Server as `yyyymmdd` - 2019-06-04. If you only supply the Date, time is assumed as midnight - so `20190604` is equivalent to `2019-06-04T00:00:00`.

Please note that if you use `2019-06-04` with the `DateTime` data type it is still culture-dependent.

If you want all the records for that specific date, you need to add another condition:

```
SELECT DateField
FROM CalendarTbl
WHERE DateField => '20190604'
AND DateField < '20190605'
```